# IE < 9 CSS3 Transition Effect Cheats?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, css

Are there any "cheat" mechanisms similar to [IE7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) available for browsers that do not support CSS3 transitions so that if you insert CSS3 transition elements into pages it will translate them to javascript methods?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, there are a couple:

- http://louisremi.github.com/jquery.transition.js/test/index.html
- http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/