# CSS Animation for fading background colors

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to make a button's background color change from a color to another on hover with fade effect? I know this can be done in javascript but I'd rather only use css for this.

Comment: "css background change on hover" had appr. 2,8mio hits...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[CSS3 transition property](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp) is your solution.

```
.btn {
  background-color: lightblue;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
     -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* FF4+ */
      -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* IE10 */
       -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Opera 10.5+ */
          transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}  

.btn:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;  
}
```

Comment: Yes I think. See this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933062/ie-9-css3-transition-effect-cheats).

Answer (score -1):

Try this css,

```
button{background-color:#888;}
button:hover{background-color:#CCC;}
​
```

HTML is,

```
<button>Test</button>​
```

Working code : http://jsfiddle.net/HJmK9/