# HTML5/CSS3 Modal Box Compatibility with IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, cross-browser

I'm playing around with HTML5/CSS3 for the first time and have used a nice wee link to a dialog (modal) display on one of my pages.

This works like a dream in Chrome/Firefox but not in IE (Possibly not a huge surprise).

In IE (9) the page actually freezes entirely when trying to click on a link..

Could anyone point out exactly what part of the CSS is incompatible and if there is a fix available?

Code is found below, thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
 <td><a href="#Code1">Get Date / Without Time</a></td>


 <div id="Code1" class="modalDialog">

 <div>

<a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
<h2>TITLE</h2>
<p>TEXT</p>
        </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.modalDialog {
        position: fixed;
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        overflow: auto;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        z-index: 99999;
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .modalDialog:target {
        opacity:1;
        pointer-events: auto;
    }

    .modalDialog > div {
        width: 40%;
        height: auto;
        position: relative;
        margin: 10% auto;
        padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #999999);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #999999);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #999999);
    }

    .close {
        background: #285C82;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        line-height: 25px;
        position: absolute;
        right: -12px;
        text-align: center;
        top: -10px;
        width: 24px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
        -moz-border-radius: 12px;
        border-radius: 12px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    }

    .close:hover { color: #285C82; background: #FFFFFF; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9 [does not support](http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events) CSS `pointer-events`. In all browsers the dialog is invisibly (opaquely) rendered over the whole page but in IE9 the pointer events are *not* ignored and therefore the dialog is blocking the click event on the anchor.

There is probably a cleaner way to solve this but as a workaround you could add the following properties in a separate stylesheet for IE using [*conditional comments*](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

```
.modalDialog {
    display:none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
    display:block;
}
```

Another workaround is to give the `<a>` position and a z-index > the z-index of the dialog.

Also, CSS `transition` [is not supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=transition) in IE9 so you might need to look for an alternative, maybe [IE < 9 CSS3 Transition Effect Cheats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933062/ie-9-css3-transition-effect-cheats) will help.

Comment: Will need those for some time, IE10 doesn't support `pointer-events` either!

Answer (score 2):

in all the tags where you wrote -webkit-, -moz- or -o- you didnt wrote -ms- which is the prefix for internet explorer.
transition doesnt work at internet explorer at all, you can see the internet explorer support in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp)

boaz