# Does IE9 support transition CSS3 effects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I used below code for Page transition effect but that does not support IE9 browser. I must apply that effect in IE9 browser. so, what can i do?

```
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;  
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease;
transition: all 1s ease;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE < 9 CSS3 Transition Effect Cheats?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933062/ie-9-css3-transition-effect-cheats)

Comment: <9 version that has not support effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS Transitions are not supported in IE9.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

Also, IE10 uses unprefixed transition. (so -ms-transition is of no use here)

Use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect if css transitions are supported, else fallback with jQuery Animate for all browsers (including IE9) that do not support CSS transitions.

```
if(!Modernizr.csstransitions) { // CSS ANimations Not supported.
//ADD YOUR CODE HERE
}
```